# RequireJS: bundling module with plugins

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd

I'm using an external library that consists of a "core" plus multiple "extensions". Every extension depends on the core. Think jQuery or Rx.

What I need to do is to bundle the core together with some of the extensions and provide that as a single module. On the surface, it seems that something like this should work:

```
// lib.js
define(
    "lib",
    ["./Lib/lib", "./Lib/ext1", "./Lib/ext2"], 
    function(lib) { return lib; }
);
```

The problem, however, is that extensions expect the "core" to be available by the module ID of "lib". In other words, "ext1" is defined like this:

```
// Lib/ext1.js
define( ["lib"], function(lib) { lib.ext.someFunc = ... } );
```

One can spot the problem here: because the name "lib" refers to my "bundled" module instead of just the "core", it is not yet available at the time ext1 loads, so the whole chain becomes circular and falls apart.

Of course, I could map the core to "lib" and then give my bundled module a different name:

```
// main.js
require.config( { paths: { lib: "Lib/lib" } } );

// lib.js
define(
    "bundled-lib",
    ["./Lib/lib", "./Lib/ext1", "./Lib/ext2"], 
    function(lib) { return lib; }
);
```

But that approach is highly undesirable for a few reasons:

1. It's just plain inconvenient to use a different name. There is no good common sense name that I could use instead, "lib" is pretty much the only option, and anything else will look ugly.
2. But more importantly, this may lead to hard-to-catch bugs. Down the road, when I have forgotten all about this little hack, I may just follow my common sense and import "lib" instead of "bundled-lib", and then my extensions will not get loaded. Or sometimes they will. If some other module which correctly imports "bundled-lib" just happens to load before the new "lib"-importing module, then it will work. Otherwise, it won't. Meaning that my application will either crash or not depending on whether certain features have or have not been used.

**So the bottom line is,** I would like to bundle the core with extensions, call the bundle "lib", but somehow have the extensions to only import the core, while not modifying the extensions themselves.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just a few hours after asking the question, I have found the answer on my own.

The answer is - the [map config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) of RequireJS.
Basically, as it turns out, I can define a mapping of module names as seen by each module individually.

In particular, my problem as it is described in the question, would be solved by the following configuration:

```
require.config( {
    map: {
        'ext1': { 'lib': 'Lib/lib' }
        'ext2': { 'lib': 'Lib/lib' }
    }
} );
```

This will make both ext1 and ext2 see module 'Lib/lib' as 'lib', while not affecting all other modules.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to jQuery and jQuery plugins. Seems like you have an understanding of the implications, so you just need to make a decision on which method is preferred.

I would not go with a module that returns 'lib', which already has those extensions. If you feel feel that you only need single dependency where you reference extended lib, just go with your 'bundled-lib' approach.

To stick with best practices and not confuse yourself in a future I believe it would be best not to bundle, but for those modules where you rely on extensions, include dependency to your core lib and those extensions:

```
  define(['lib', 'ext1'], function(lib){
    // module definition...
  });
```

This way it is VERY clear what are dependencies for this module. I'm sure you thought about it and I just hope it help you with making a decision.

Comment: What happens if I forget to include the "ext" dependency in some module sometime down the road? The code will sometimes work and sometimes not work - depending on the exact use scenario, and it will be very hard to catch. I would like very much to protect from that.

Comment: How can you forget to include dependency in the module? It has to work when you are developing it. Other dependent code will load it's own dependencies.

Comment: I can forget to include it, because it is not actually referenced anywhere in my code. Consider this: `require(['jQuery', 'jQueryUI'], function($, jqui) { ... })`. While I may use the extensions provided by jQueryUI, I never reference the `jqui` argument itself. Therefore, if I forget to include it, my code will still be valid, the browser will not complain, and neither will tools like JSLint or TypeScript. And when I load it in the browser to test, chances are it will even work fine, because some other module has probably already loaded jQueryUI.

Comment: And then, once I get into habit of forgetting to mention jQueryUI in my dependencies, things will eventually start to break sporadically, and I will have the fun of my life trying to find the cause.

Comment: And speaking of TypeScript. With TypeScript, this problem is even worse, because TypeScript will not include a module in the list of dependencies when that module is not actually referenced in the code.

Comment: I understand, here you would have to have discipline and be aware of what module is using. Then looks like you have no other way than going with your 'bundle-lib' methodology.

Comment: It is never a good idea to rely on everybody's discipline and competence. That approach will always fail, there is no way around it. That's why we have all these complicated systems like AMD, type systems, unit testing, static code analysis, etc. So then you answer is basically "there is no way", right? That is sad, but thank you for responding.

Comment: Yes, that is my answer. Give an update if you come up with a better way.

Comment: Found it! :-) Check out my own answer.